# SwiftUI preview fails when using UIHostingController when creating UIHostingController outside viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have some code that causes SwiftUI previews to fail but will run successfully in the simulator and on a device. The SwiftUI previews failure diagnostics message is:

```
PreviewUpdateTimedOutError: Updating took more than 5 seconds

Updating a preview from ViewControllerPreviews in NestedTest.app (9218) took more than 5 seconds.
```

I have boiled the issue down to a minimal amount of code:

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

let createHostInInit = true

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var host: TestViewHost? = nil
    
    init() {
        if createHostInInit {
            host = TestViewHost()
        }

        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    // Note: this is here to satisfy the compiler and to allow running this
    // in the simulator as part of a default new project.
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        if createHostInInit {
            host = TestViewHost()
        }

        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if !createHostInInit {
            host = TestViewHost()
        }
        
        if let host = self.host {
            addChild(host)
            self.view.addSubview(host.view)
            host.didMove(toParent: self)
            host.view.frame = self.view.bounds
        }
    }
}

class TestViewHost: UIHostingController<TestView> {
    init() {
        super.init(rootView: TestView())
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hi there!")
    }
}

struct UIViewControllerPreviewer: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let viewController: UIViewController
    
    init(viewController: UIViewController) {
        self.viewController = viewController
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
        return viewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
        // Do nothing because this is only for previews
    }
}

struct ViewControllerPreviews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        return UIViewControllerPreviewer(viewController: ViewController())
    }
}
```

If `createHostInInit = true` then the previews fail. If `createHostInInit = false` then the previews work. In either of these cases the UI looks correct in the simulator or on a device. So it would seem that something about the preview environment gets cranky about when a UIHostingController is created before viewDidLoad().
Did I miss some documentation for UIHostingController describing these limitations? Is this a bug?
This can be tested in Xcode by creating a new iOS single view project and dropping this code into ViewController.swift.

Thanks